# how to work html page responsive whene use margin in css

Tags: html, css

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*background-color: DodgerBlue;*/
}

.flex-container > div {
 /* background-color: #f1f1f1;*/
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#first-section{
    width: 30%;

}

#second-section{
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    background: white
}
```

```html
<body>
<div header>
  <img width="100%" src="https://backgrounddownload.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/header-background-6.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="first-section">        <h2>Design Trade Program</h2>
                <p>        
    Qualified interior decorators, designers, stylists and architects can enjoy an exclusive 20% discount on full-priced merchandise with no minimum purchase.
    </p>
    <p>
    Want to join?  Please fill in the below details and we will follow up with you directly within one to two business days. Additional services are available to design professionals depending on your location.
    </p></div>

  <div id="second-section">  <h2>Design Trade Program</h2>
    <p>        
Qualified interior decorators, designers, stylists and architects can enjoy an exclusive 20% discount on full-priced merchandise with no minimum purchase.
</p>
<p>
Want to join?  Please fill in the below details and we will follow up with you directly within one to two business days. Additional services are available to design professionals depending on your location.</div>  
</div>

</body>
```

hi ,this code its ok for normal window  but when show on tablet or mobile its not good,i want first show header then first-section finally second-second when use mobile,how i can use true show when show this code in mobile(worked responsive)
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* background-color: DodgerBlue; */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container > div {
  /* background-color: #f1f1f1;*/
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

 #first-section{
  width: 30%;
}

#second-section{
  width: 60%;
  margin-top: -200px;
  background: white
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #first-section{
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  #second-section{
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    background: white
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is to use percent not the pixel values and I think the negative values won't work in margin.

Answer (score 0):

for this, you can use `media queries`in CSS.

For example, for showing the content on your website on mobile, I would do:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .flex-container { flex-flow: column; }
    .flex-container > div { width: 100% }
    .second-section { margin-top: 10px }
}
```

To also cover the tablet size, just change `(max-width: 767px)` to `(max-width: 1024px)` and the sections will stack on tablet as well.

So, your full CSS would be:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*background-color: DodgerBlue;*/
}

.flex-container > div {
 /* background-color: #f1f1f1;*/
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#first-section{
    width: 30%;

}

#second-section{
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    background: white
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .flex-container { flex-flow: column; }
    .flex-container > div { width: 100% }
    .second-section { margin-top: 10px }
}
```

Here is a list of useful media queries for different devices: [CSS Media Queries for Desktop, Tablet, Mobile](https://gist.github.com/gokulkrishh/242e68d1ee94ad05f488)

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code in your style file.Hope so this gives your expected output for mobile or iPad.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1279px) {
 .flex-container {
   flex-direction: column;
  }
  #first-section, #second-section {
   width: 100%;
  }

}
```